# Excel Find next Value in a range with VLookup or Index Match

Tags: excel, vba, find, vlookup

With Vlookup I can find a Value in a column, based on a search criteria (=AAA) and display a Value from another column (Text1). No problems so far. If there are two equal Values in a column, Vlookup finds the first Value and displays it (Text1). Now I need to find the next Value based onthe same search criteris (AAA). How do I find the next value with search criteria AAA to display text3(!)?

Column A Column B
AAA      Text1
BBB      Text2
AAA      Text3

Comment: You may get better help regarding Excel formulae at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).. Did a search for "vlookup identical values" and noticed [this](http://excelbyjoe.com/3-ways-to-deal-with-multiple-matches-with-vlookup-in-excel/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about multiple instances of lookup value in your table array. You can create  a variable which counts the number of times your lookup value appears, and concatenate it with the lookup value and use that as the new lookup value. 
Say 'xx' appears twice. Now it would look like this: 'xx1','xx2'
So now you have unique keys and you can use the vlookup function with a lookup value 'xx2' and get the return value.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options:
Insert 1 Column before Column A. Enter formula in A1 =B1&COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)
It will give you result AAA1; BBB2; AAA2 and etc.

For example: you need result in the cell G1 based on values in F1.

Enter formula in G1 
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(F1,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)),$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)
Enter AAA in F1 and G1 will give you result TEXT1
Enter AAA (second times) in F2 and G2 will give you result TEXT2

I hope we understood you question properly.

Comment: and Formula will show Error if all possible versions are already shown. For example: you entered AAA 21 times and in the table AAA is only 20.